# Best solution for making a LAN with 2 untwisted lines

Tags: ethernet, power-line-communication

I need to provide a best solution for establish a LAN for old train carriages in order to transfer low quality video surveillance data.

Only existing lines are 2 wires untwisted throughout all cabins, max number of cabins are 16-18. Hopefully can achieve 100Mbps bandwidth within the LAN. High reliability.

```
------------   ------------  ------------
|        =========================      |
|          |   |          |  |          |
| cabin 1  |   | cabin 2  |  | cabin N  |
------------   ------------  ------------
```

My thoughts are:

- power line communications (like existing power line modems) attached in parallel to the bus.
- ADSL connections, where cabin N always connect to cabin N+1. wires broken into (N-1) pieces, and total (N-1) connections.
- VDSL similar concept to ADSL

Has anyone had similar experience before?

ALSO: They are moving and LAN is (digital local area network) and My application with based on UDP+TCP and IP protocols

Comment: Power line comms may work. ADSL and VDSL are designed to run over twisted pair (the telephone system uses twisted pair).

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that these "old train carriages" are stationary? If so, Joe's answer worries about things like traction motor noise which don't apply.

Comment: Sorry they are in operation and moving.

Answer (score 1):

Having done radiated noise tests by railroad passing coaxial cable TV residential distribution lines, in the 90's, I would avoid baseband and VHF and look for a slotted aloha UHF solution 0.3~3GHz, TDM SCADA solution with E1 data rates of 2.048 Mbps and up with high res video compressed with MPEG but only 60 frames per second  shared by 20 transmitters. Controller requests interleaved frames from each source to asigned time slots or more for one channel requiring more attention. Low speed controller can be sent securely with encrypted spread spectrum for time slots of each unique address that responds. I don't have current commercial solutions, but I would avoid baseband and VHF due to traction motor noise.  Many tradeoffs between cost, reliability, security and susceptibility to interference.